# Java constructor error in child class

Tags: java

```
class Person 
{
    String name = "No name";

    public Person(String nm)
    {
        name = nm;
    }
}
class Employee1 extends Person
{
    String empID ="0000";
    public Employee1(String id)
    {                            // Line 1
        empID = id;
    }
}
public class EmployeeTest 
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Employee1 e = new Employee1("4321");
           Person p = new Person("Hello");
           System.out.println(e.empID);
       }
   }
```

I get compilation error saying `constructor Person in class Person cannot be applied to given types; required String found no arguments` but I am passing arguments for both the parent and the child class when I create new object in main method. Unable to figure out why compilation error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly create the parent class, passing it a `name` as the `Person` construtor requires:

```
public Employee1(String id) {
    super("person name");   // create the parent
    empID = id;
}
```

Or maybe something like:

```
public Employee1(String id, String name) {
    super(name);   // create the parent
    empID = id;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee1 e = new Employee1("4321", "Hello");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why do I have to create constructor of parent from a child class? Normally parent class constructor will be created and expecting the values when a object is created using "new operator" right?

Answer (score 1):

Because constructor in child class implicitly calls the parameter-less constructor of it's immediate super class only if the default constructor does not explicitly call a superclass constructor so

```
public Employee1(String id)
{                            // Line 1
    empID = id;
}
```

will try to call constructor in super class as you have not called it explicitly  so you can say your code will be like this

```
public Employee1(String id)
{
    super();                            // Line 1
    empID = id;
}
```

but in you parent class there is no "no argument" constructor, so it is giving error like this.

Comment: by default a no-arg constructor will be created automatically right ?

Comment: yes,  the compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors

Answer (score 0):

On the constructor of `employee` you must call first the constructor of `person` as in `super(name);` and then initialize the subclass

```
class Employee1 extends Person
{
    String empID ="0000";
    public Employee1(String id, String name)
    {                            // Line 1
        super(name);
        empID = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The implicit super constructor `Person()` is undefined.

So you must explicitly invoke its parent constructor.